# Create dataset out of x_train and y_train

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, speech-recognition, dataloader

How to put the x_train and y_train into a model for training?
The x_train is a tensor of size (3000, 13).
The y_train is of size (3000, 1)
That is for each element of x_train (1, 13), the respective y label is one digit from y_train.
if I do:

```
train_data = (train_feat, train_labels)
print(train_data[0].shape)
print(train_data[1].shape)

torch.Size([3082092, 13])
torch.Size([3082092, 1])
train_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset=train_data,
                                batch_size= 7,
                                shuffle=True)
```

The dataloader  does not return the batch size, but returns the whole dataset instead

Comment: I think you should provide the `hstack` with the `axis` parameter

Comment: @sagi Thanks for the comment. I actually removed the `hstack`. My problem is how to tell which x_train item has which label, maybe a collate function can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset) constructor:

```py
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

dataset = data_utils.TensorDataset(train_feat, train_labels)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=7, shuffle=True)
```